# Is the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x (x^2-1)} \, dx$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

> Is the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x (x^2-1)} \, dx$ convergent?

I've seen this question has an answer already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129366/188391):

But I wonder, Why not just:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x (x^2-1)} \, dx \le \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x (x^2-1)} \, dx \le \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2-1)} \, dx \le \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \lt \infty$$

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: The integral converges as the answers in the link provided say. In fact it turns to be $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Comment: When dealing with inequalities, you should be aware of sign. So notice that both $\log x$ and $x^2 - 1$ has negative sign on $(0, 1)$. This invalidates your 1st inequality as well as the 3rd inequality.

Comment: It is wrong to write that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \lt \infty $$ since this integral is **divergent**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}\,dx =4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log u}{u^4-1}\,dx=2K+\frac{\pi^2}{4},\tag{1}$$
where $K$ is the Catalan constant, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}u^m\log u = -\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}. \tag{2}$$
For the same reason,
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}\,dx = 4\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log u}{u^4-1}\,du = 4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{v^2\log v}{v^4-1}\,dv=-2K+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\tag{3} $$
hence by adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ we simply get:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}.\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ is divergent :

$$\int_t^1 \frac{1}{x^2}dx = \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_t^1 = \frac{1}{t}-1 \to_{t\to 0} +\infty$$